# Is it possible to program setText from another Java file in android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

Please understand me and my problem first.(i explain very badly so)

My files are **ActivityMain.java** And **activity_main.xml** which are connected to each other (as far as i know), means if I am calling

```
final TextView helloTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_id);
helloTextView.setText(R.string.user_greeting);
```

in `(R.id.text_view_id)`, `text_view_id` can only be connect to `android:id="@+id/text_view_id"` which only present it activity_main.xml (As i understand). And correct me if i am wrong if the `text_view_id` is not present in the activity_main.xml it ll throw an error `"NullPointerException"`

**Now My Question is - there is anyway that i can interchange data without getting `NullPointerException` ?**

What i mean is want to create new ActivityMain2.java, write the javacode in  ActivityMain2.java but `android:id="@+id/text_view_id"` ll be present on activity_main.java.

I tried several ways searched stack overflow but failed. Either i am getting `NullPointerException` or the text field do not get updated from code.

My skill level : Just a beginer

Comment: you are calling second activitty after ActivityMain.java ?

Comment: `My files are ActivityMain.java And activity_main.xml which are connected to each other (as far as i know), ` No. Not automatically. They are only connected if you used setContenView(...activity_main.xml). So only when you used that xml layout for that activity. You can use the same layout for as many activities as you want.

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to create another

> activity2.xml

file in the layout folder, then you put another

> android:id="@+id/text_view_id"

file in the layout.
and since you are a beginner i recommend the beginner's course by Google [here](https://www.udacity.com/google)

Comment: yes! it's possible to have an activity without a layout file. only that you'll have nothing to show on the screen except you create your layout programmatically